# Change text of one specific context menu item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, contextmenu, android-contextmenu

I've created a context menu for my recycler view items. In the menu I have Watch (like favourites), Share and Hide. Now what I want to do is get the specific position of the Recycler View and check if the Watch or Hide button has been pressed. How can I go about doing this? I've used a flag but that just checks the whole Recycler View so that doesn't work.

I can show source code on request too. I know it needs to go in my Adapter but can't figure out the position of it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just add a boolean variable in your List<model> to check whether to show Watch or Hide button

Comment: Whereabouts, in the adapter I know, but in the OnBind or somewhere else?

Comment: where you are setting your onClickListener

Comment: @RahulKhurana in the ViewHolder

Comment: okk then there will be no problem. use **getAdapterPosition()** method when user clicked the clicked on button and then use that position to update value in your model class.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about that. Thank you. Do you want to put it as an answer and I'll give you kudos for it?

Comment: i posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a boolean variable in your List to check whether to show Watch or Hide button. 
use getAdapterPosition() method when user clicked the clicked on button and then use that position to update value in your model class.